# change the NumberSpinner attr dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have initialized the NumberSpinner in the following way.

```
var spinner = new dijit.form.NumberSpinner({
                  name:"spinner",
                    value: "0",
                     smallDelta:"10",
                    constraints: {
                        min: "0"
                    },
                    style:'width:100px'
                },
                "container");
```

what i need to do is change the smallDelta value dynamically according to other selections. Is there any way to remove smallDelta attribute. If it can be done  I can use set method to set the attribute with different value. any help??
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? You can simply not include it in your object literal, or you can set it equal to some other variable instead of a hardcoded string. Can you explain in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the smallDelta value dynamically using `spinner.set('smallDelta', yourValue);`

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBhPF/):

markup:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div id="container">

    </div>
    <input id="increaseDelta" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" label="increase delta">

    <input id="decreaseDelta" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" label="decrease delta">
</body>
```

javascript:

```
dojo.require('dijit.form.NumberSpinner');
dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');
dojo.ready(function() {
    var spinner = new dijit.form.NumberSpinner({
        id: 'spinner',
        name: "spinner",
        value: "0",
        smallDelta: "10",
        constraints: {
            min: "0"
        },
        style: 'width:100px'
    }, "container");

    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('increaseDelta'), 'onClick', function() {
        var spin = dijit.byId('spinner');
        var currentDelta = spin.get('smallDelta');
        console.log(currentDelta);
        spin.set('smallDelta', parseInt(currentDelta) + 10)
    });

    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('decreaseDelta'), 'onClick', function() {
        var spin = dijit.byId('spinner');
        var currentDelta = spin.get('smallDelta');
        console.log(currentDelta);
        spin.set('smallDelta', parseInt(currentDelta) - 10)
    });

});
```

Comment: spinner.set("value", 0); - you are the saver!